# React Native get navigator instance

Tags: reactjs, react-native

In my render method I am using a sidebar which needs to wrap around the Navigator component but also needs to pass the navigator in order for link clicks within the side bar to work

```
render() {
  const sidebar = <SideBar navigator={this.refs.navigator} />;

  return (
    <SideMenu menu={sidebar} isOpen={true}>
      <Navigator
        ref='navigator'
        renderScene={this.renderScene}
        initialRoute={{id: 'search_results', title: 'Search results'}}
        navigationBar={
          <NavigationBar
            routeMapper={this.navigationBarRouteMapper}
            style={NavbarStyles.navbar}
            navigator={this.refs.navigator}
          />
        }
      />
    </SideMenu>
  );
}
```

How would I get the navigator for the `const sidebar`? Or is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: I use NavigatorIOS and something like this works for me: `this.refs.navigator._owner._instance.refs.navigator`

Answer (score 0):

```
render() {
  let navigator = (<Navigator
        ref='navigator'
        renderScene={this.renderScene}
        initialRoute={{id: 'search_results', title: 'Search results'}}
        navigationBar={
          <NavigationBar
            routeMapper={this.navigationBarRouteMapper}
            style={NavbarStyles.navbar}
            navigator={this.refs.navigator}
          />
        }
      />);
  const sidebar = <SideBar navigator={navigator} />;

  return (
    <SideMenu menu={sidebar} isOpen={true}>
     {navigator}
    </SideMenu>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I implemented your suggestion and paired it with the code Cherniv mentioned in the comment. However, when I use `navigator._owner._instance.refs.navigator.state` I get an empty object. Yet, when I `console.log` `navigator._owner._instance.refs.navigator` I can see the `state` object

Comment: Why do you need the state of the component in which owns navigator inside SideMenu ? If you need to navigate, you can just use this.props.navigator.push etc